# GWT designer could not add celltable appropriately in uibinder mode

Tags: uibinder, gwt-designer

For I can not add TextColumn directly  as I do in GWT Java UI mode, I got a "You can not add abstract component" error.
I am using full version of  GWT Designer 2.4.2.r37x201110181249 .
And I noticed the palette content is different in UIBinder Mode and GWT JAVA UI mode after all.
Is this supposed to be that way?Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UiBinder supports a subset of what is available in GWT Java, so the GWT Designer palette reflects that. The work around would be to use GWT Java.

Comment: Thanks Eric,I saw your Google IO session video this year,really inspiring.But in this case I think uibinder is part of the design philosophy that separate UI and logic, it's better integrate full function into GWT designer uibinder mode.